# What does this compile-time error mean? "An object reference is required to access non-static member."

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to use a method from other script but it is not working. I receive the following error:

> Assets/Scripts/Licznik.cs(21,25): error CS0120: An object reference is
>   required to access non-static member `SceneLoader.LoadNextScene()'

I want to use method from other script

```
[SerializeField] int BlocksToDestroy;
[SerializeField] int BlocksDestroyed;

// Update is called once per frame
void Update ()
{
    if (BlocksToDestroy == BlocksDestroyed)
    {
        SceneLoader.LoadNextScene();
    }
}

public void LoadNextScene()
{
    int currentrySceneIndex = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
    SceneManager.LoadScene(currentrySceneIndex +1);
}
```

Comment: You are not creating an instance of the object you are calling, so that method either needs to be static or you need to create an instance of thee class.

Comment: Sorry I'm still learning.

Comment: No need to apologize for learning. You might consider reading up on the `static` modifier: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static (that's a bit of an easier read than the C# language specification). You may find spending some time learning C# itself will help you in Unity

Answer (score 3):

The error is giving you the answer. At the point that you use it, the object of type SceneLoader has to have been created. You need to instantiate the object to get a reference to it.

```
SceneLoader sceneLoader = new SceneLoader();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class called SceneLoader that is static, define the method LoadNextScene as public, you're trying to use a class within a static context that requires an object be instantiated first.

```
public class SceneLoader
{
    public static void LoadNextScene()
    {
        int currentSceneIdx = SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex;
        SceneManager.LoadScene(currentSceneIdx +1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Now the class is correct but the calling code needs to be fixed as well.

Comment: @Steve You're correct, the static modifier should be on the method declaration.  My bad.  Also, I wasn't sure if SceneLoader was an actual class he was attempting to use I was unable to find it in the Unity documentation, hence a wrapper class to assist him was my goal.